# Display list of users per project on Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins, ldap

I have several jobs on our Jenkins and each job has different users. We are using "Enable project-based security" option on each job configurations and is connected to LDAP. How can I extract the list of users per job. I have been checking this on the Script Console but have not any luck.